# Why does WPF lack HTML support?

Tags: html, wpf, frame

Why does WPF lack HTML support?  I know there is the `Frame`.  But that shouldn't even be considered a WPF control (not, at least, when it is rendering HTML). I know there is a hack with a floating window, but that's crap!

I just want to show a static HTML document in my WPF application, in a window with rounded corners and a drop shadow. I'm hitting a brick wall, and I'm incredibly frustrated!

HELP!

Comment: it would be helpful to edit the title of this question to be gramatically correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're pretty limited with the functionality built in to WPF.  WPF doesn't know how to render HTML on its own - it relies on the native Internet Explorer web browser activex control (aka Trident) to do this.  activex controls are rendered in "child windows" on top of any other content in your wpf window.  nothing you can really do about this.

the best alternative is probably to switch to a Google Chrome-based control which does not have such a limitation:  http://wpfchromium4.codeplex.com/

Comment: To expensive (they charge for commercial release), and I'm using .NET 3.5.

Comment: sorry, you're out of luck then

Answer (score 5):

Can you just embed a web browser control in your WPF app? Your WPF app can then have the nice looking drop shadow around the WebBrowser control, and then WebBrowser control can host your static HTML.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/web-browser-control-in-wpf/

Comment: This will allow the window to use opacity?  That's the problem with Frame, if your window supports opacity the HTML content becomes invisible.

Comment: Can this capture the windows.external.notify("") inside the WPF code same like the windows phone is doing? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify(v=vs.105).aspx